# Interacting with Exchange 2007

Tags: .net, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server

At the moment I am using powershell hosted in an asp.net app to communicate with Exchange, and create Exchange objects. Does anyone know of any other means of interacting with Exchange? These methods need to allow the creation of items such as mailboxes and distribution lists, so Exchange Web Services is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since powershell is .NET, you should be able to reflect (with Reflector) upon Exchange assemblies to find out what each command really does inside and do the same - thus skipping the whole powershell thingy.